# Howto redirect cheese webcam effect to new video device

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, webcam, obs-studio, v4l2

I am on ubuntu 20.04, but v4l2 package is not working: so I installed it from here

```
git clone git@github.com:umlaeute/v4l2loopback

make

sudo insmod v4l2loopback.ko exclusive_caps=1 video_nr=1 card_label="Fake"
```

now I can see "Fake" webcam with black screen in discord... how do I go on from here, using e. g. `ffmpeg`, in order to see the cheese webcam effect as new "Fake" webcam? It has to be a simple `/dev/video0` to `/dev/video1` streaming, but I cannot accomplish it.

Update 20201023:
Now I have OBS studio installed: all I see is a plugin to record discord sources in OBS... how do I setup the following situation:

```
                                  cheese
                              /            \
                     webcam                      discord
                              \            /
                                obs studio
```

The upper or lower path should be alternatively used. When I connect the webcam to either `cheese` or `obs studio` discord "sees" a blackscreen as webcam source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and tried a solution for obs-studio from here (German, paywall):

https://www.heise.de/ratgeber/Videokonferenzen-Virtuelle-Webcam-mit-OBS-Studio-unter-Windows-und-Linux-4766615.html